# Opening a word file in Recent documents - Office Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, file-recovery

There was a `word .doc` file I was working with in my flash drive, then after I removed the flash it has disappeared.

Now I can see the file name in office in `recent documents`, is there any chance I can get the file copied somehow somewhere on my local computer?

The file is removed from the flash drive and when I try to open it, it says `The file could not be found`.

Comment: The "Recents" are just links to the files, they do not contain the data for the file, and it is rare that any program would move the file itself prior to working with it. That leaves word opening .tmp files, with the same data in it, depending on what you were doing. and any auto saves that would exist. If the file was just deleted and not overwritten yet, doing a un-delete or recovery on the flash drive might bring the file back.  In many cases you will waste more time messing with stuff, then if you just re-write and use better patterns next time.

Comment: @Psycogeek exactly, is there any chance I can get to temp files?

Comment: @Psycogeek there must be some temporary files regarding the edits made to the file on my local computer, how can I get to them?

Comment: @Psycogeek and the recovery software seem not to work :(

Comment: At the least we would need to know the version of word/office that you are using? The tmp in the old versions (really old) was usually opened in the same location as the file, and was removed when the file is closed out of the program. In that case it would just be one more thing to look for when playing with undeleting.

Comment: What version of Word are you using? Hopefully, you are using Office 2013 (Word 2013).

Comment: @sunk818 no it's 2010 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word 2013, you can potentially recover unsaved files.

You can also do a search for the Word document on all the computer drives.

[image]